# When should 之 be used as a particle?

Tags: usage, particles

When should 之 be used as a particle? There doesn't seem to be a straightforward answer on Nciku. On [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E4%B9%8B#Mandarin), the entry states:

> Indicates that the previous word has possession of the next one. In
>   English it functions like 's or like the word "of" but with the
>   position of possessor and possessee switched. 的 (de) is more common
>   but 之 is used in many set expressions.

However, in the contexts I've seen so far, the 之 particle is used more like 的 in some sense (rather like the Japanese の perhaps) - for isntance, [银之匙 as a translation of a manga title](http://zh.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E9%93%B6%E4%B9%8B%E5%8C%99_Silver_Spoon) - so the usage seems to be more of a "link" between two different words as some sort of descriptor or identifier (in terms of a quality of the second word, in a sense).

That said, the purpose of the 之 in 之前 or 之後 seems to be slightly different than in the other example I gave. Taking all this into account, when should I should 之, outside of expressions that have it already (such as 之前), and what makes in different from 的 in phrases such as "银之匙"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

之 is the **wenyan** equivalent of Mandarin 的.  Here are some examples from a Classical Chinese textbook:

> 鄰人之父 >    鄰居的老人       ‘an old man who lived next door’
>
> 衛國之法   >  衛國的法律       ‘the laws of Wei’
>
> 仁義 之 道  >  仁義的 道理      ‘the doctrine of benevolence and righteousness’

Because parts of speech in wenyan are quite flexible, using 之 to link two terms can have the effect of nominalizing the second one, like this:

> 王來      ‘the king comes’  >>   王之來    ‘the king’s coming/the arrival of the king’

之 has other meanings in wenyan, too.  The most important of these is probably its use as a third person pronoun he/she/it.

In **formal written Mandarin**, 之 can appear in either of these functions.  It would be interesting to hear from a native speaker about usage here.  I consulted a book called ‘A Learners’ Handbook of Modern Chinese Written Expressions’ by Yu Feng (Chinese U. of Hong Kong Press).  He suggests a couple of uses:

- In idioms like 之後, 之中  etc.  For example:

> 美國總統的中東之行     ‘the US President’s Middle East visit’

Notice both ‘de’ and ‘zhi’ occur in this phrase – clearly you can’t simply replace the one with the other to achieve a formal style.

- In a pattern ‘2-character noun + 之 + 1-character adjective’.  This also creates a noun phrase, i.e. nominalizes like in the ‘king’s coming’ example.

> 品種之多  ‘a large quantity' [of goods at an exhibition]

There are also some set expressions with this pattern that you might use in writing, like 十天之內  ‘within ten days’.

- As a third person pronoun, according to Yu Feng mainly in idioms:

> 等閑視之     ‘regard it as unimportant’
>
> 受之有愧     ‘to feel shame in accepting it’

So, if you encounter 之 in titles like in the example you gave, I would read it as meaning 的 but also as indicating some sort of formal/classical/literary/archaic quality.  Personally I would avoid using it except in set phrases.  Unless you do a lot of formal writing at an advanced level, in which case it wouldn’t hurt to go to the source and learn a bit of wenyan!

Answer (score 0):

> 银之匙

Here "之" has no real meaning but it's **just a 助词 to modify the noun (匙) to make it a part of the fixed phrase (usually used in WenYan sentence)**. In fact this "之" is usually ignored by shorting it as "银匙"。

Sometimes, "之" can be also used to link a subject with predicate verb to be a part of sentence.

大道**之**行，天下为公。

For more about the usage of “之”, you can look up here：http://www.zdic.net/z/15/js/4E4B.htm